# c++ initialization of struct with std::list included

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following question.

Check the below block of code, it initializes my members of my structure correctly.

```
typedef struct
{
    int var00;
    int var01;
}struct_;

int main()
{


    struct_ my_struct;
    memset(&my_struct,'\0',sizeof(struct_));
    return 0;
}
```

My new structure now(see below), includes also an std::list. What I have to do now,
to keep the memset command in the code?

```
typedef struct
{
    int var00;
    int var01;
    std::list<int> my_list
}struct_list_included;

int main()
{


    struct_list_included my_struct;
    memset(&my_struct,'\0',sizeof(struct_list_included));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not simply provide a constructor? Also, those typedefs are not needed in C++.

Comment: If you are coming from a C background and are learning C++ I suggest you get yourself a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  Your code has a lot of C-ism's in it that are unnecessary as C++ has built in mechanics to do these things.

Answer (score 1):

`std::list` is *not* a *POD* type, so I don't think you can do this via `memset()`.